# <spring:bind> to display Map type property of bean class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Login Class

```
import.java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login implements serializable {

    private Map<String,Object> values;    

        public Map<String, Object> getValues() {    
            return values;    
        }    

        public void setValues(Map<String, Object> values) {    
            this.values = values;    
        }  
}
```

and I have added the two values in the Map from LoginController

```
Login login=new Login();

Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();  
    map.put("loginName", "abc");  
    map.put("loginid", "ddd");

login.setValues(map);
```

I want to access these value on the login.jsp using 
"spring:bind path".

How should I do that?

Comment: you are missing 1 key piece of information:  how do you store the Login object in the Model?  Specifically what name do you use?  Based on your question I believe you use the name "blueberryPancake", but I'm willing to be wrong about that.

Comment: i am adding the login object in the Model by adding it as attribute like `aModelMap.addAttribute(login);`

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at an answer will be an attempt to address what appears to be the underlying problem and, as such, will not be a simple answer of the question.

The design of the Login object appears to be terrible.  Instead of storing known values (login name and login id) in a Map, expose them as members of the class. By that, I mean, do this:

```
public class Login
{
  private String loginName;
  private String loginId;

  public Login()
  {
  }

  public Login(final String theLoginName, final String theLoginId)
  {
    loginName = theLoginName;
    loginId = theLoginId;
  }

  ... getters and setters.
}

... somewhere in the code
Login login = new Login("abc", "blammy");

aModelMap.addAttribute(login);
```

Next, instead of using spring:bind to get to the Login values, use spring:form

//

Comment: Thanks DwB u are right, but i have to use this in the same manner by using the Map .so plz suggest me way of accessing Map key values (loginname,loginid) on jsp using any of spring form taglib